# How to join all columns in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like one column to have all the other columns in the data frame combined.

```
here is what the dataframe looks like
  0   1   2
0 123 321 231
1 232 321 231
2 432 432 432

dataframe name = task_ba
```

```
I would like it to look like this
   0
0 123
1 232
2 432
3 321
4 321
5 432
6 231
7 231
8 432
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest and fastest option, use the underlying numpy array:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.values.ravel(order='F'))
```

*NB. If you prefer a series, use `pd.Series` instead*

Output:

```
     0
0  123
1  232
2  432
3  321
4  321
5  432
6  231
7  231
8  432
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten())` Gives a similar result~ or `pd.DataFrame(df.values.flatten('F'))` for the same result.

Comment: @BeRT2me yes the two functions are doing the same (but `ravel` returns a view), yet you also need to pass `order='F'` to `flatten` to have the desired order.

Comment: I just timed it, why is `.ravel(order='F')` SO MUCH FASTER than `.flatten('F')`?

Comment: @BeRT2me `flatten` makes a copy of the array, `ravel` returns a view of the original array (i.e. same object). It's better to use `ravel` as the DataFrame constructor will make a copy anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pd.DataFrame.melt()` and then drop the variable column:

```py
>>> df
     0    1    2
0  123  321  231
1  232  321  231
2  432  432  432

>>> df.melt().drop("variable", axis=1)  # Drops the 'variable' column
   value
0    123
1    232
2    432
3    321
4    321
5    432
6    231
7    231
8    432
```

Or if you want `0` as your column name:

```py
>>> df.melt(value_name=0).drop("variable", axis=1)
     0
0  123
1  232
2  432
3  321
4  321
5  432
6  231
7  231
8  432
```

You can learn all this (and more!) in the [official documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).

Comment: Not necessary. Can just pass `value_name=0` in `df.melt()`.